Opensearch indexing a key with string and object
I have two application one sends response: "somestring" and other sends with object response: "{statusCode: 200}"
I had the index like below
  response:
    dynamic: true
    properties:
      statusCode:
        type: integer

With the above mapping, i am getting below error

#<Fluent::Plugin::OpenSearchErrorHandler::OpenSearchError: 400 - Rejected by OpenSearch [error type]: mapper_parsing_exception [reason]: 'object mapping for [response] tried to parse field [response] as object, but found a concrete value'>",

I am expecting to receive as any value and index if object and has statusCode, is this possible ?

Tldr;
Not sure opensearch does support it. But elasticsearch since version 8.3 added support for something called subobjects.
Demo
PUT 79180603/
{
  "mappings":{
    "subobjects": false
  }
}

POST _bulk
{"index":{"_index":"79180603"}}
{"response": "somhting string"}
{"index":{"_index":"79180603"}}
{"response.statusCode": 200}

GET 79180603/_search

